# display node type

Tags: drupal-7

> I have some custom pages in my drupal 7 site. I need to display the
>   name of the content type in each page. What function shall I use to
>   display the name of the content type?

Answer (score 1):

You could print out the content type from the node.tpl.php in your theme. The $node object gets passed to the node.tpl.php file , you you just need to echo out `<?php echo $node->type; ?>` where you want it to display.

Comment: When I use this <?php echo $node-type; ?> its displaying the numeric value '0', but I need to print the name of the content type.

Comment: Sorry my original response had a typo. it should be <?php echo $node->type; ?>